# FAT filesystem: calculate the size and search a byte

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, fat

I have this question in an Operating System test:

Given a disk of 1GB with 16KB blocks:

(1) Calculate the size of the File Allocation Table:

My Answer: since there are 2^16 blocks in the disk, we have a table with 2^16 entry, and every entry needs to store 16 bit (since there are 2^16 different blocks, we need 16 bit to identify each of them). So the size is 2^16 times 16 bit = 2^16 x 2^4 = 2^20 bit = 2^17 byte = 128Kb.

(2) Given the following table, indicate in which block are stored the following byte:  
  -byte 131080 of FileA starting at block 4.

  -byte 62230 of FileB starting at block 3.

```
Entry Content
0     10
1     2
2     0
3     6
4     1
5     8
6     7
7     11
8     12
```

So FileA is (4) -> (1) -> (2) but the problem is: since every block is 16Kb = 2^4 x 2^10 byte = 2^14 byte = 16384 byte, block 4 contains from 1 to 16384, block 1 contains from 16385 to 32768, and block 2 from 32769 to 49152, where am I supposed to find the byte 131080??? 
Where is this wrong??